# TypeError: this.props.decrementCount is not a function

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am trying to make a simple cart counter but getting this error. I am confuse that mapStateToDispatch is working or not. Imported all modules,functions properly but getting only this error when i click the ADD,Remove button

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import './cart.css';
import {product,product1} from './product.js'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import {incrementCount , decrementCount} from './actions/buttonBehave';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'

export class Cart extends Component{
    state = {
        buttonClicked : false
    }
    handleButton= () =>{
        this.setState({
            buttonClicked : true
        })
    }
    render()
    {
        return(
    <div className="cardDiv">
        <div className="card" >
           <img className="card-img-top" src={product.image} alt="Card image" height="350px" />
          <div className="card-body">
            <h4 className="card-title">{product.name}</h4>
            <p className="card-text">Model : {product.modelName}</p>
             <p className="card-text">Price : {product.price}</p>
            <a href="#" className="btn btn-primary " onClick={this.handleButton.bind(this)}> {this.state.buttonClicked ? "Add another" : "Add to cart"} </a>
            <p className="card-text">Added : {this.props.count}</p> 
            <button onClick = { () => this.props.incrementCount ()}>Remove</button>
             <button onClick = { () => this.props.decrementCount()}>ADD</button>

             <p className="card-text">{this.props.count}</p> 
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>

 );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps= (state) =>{
      return{
            count : state.count
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = () => {
  return {
   incrementCount,
    decrementCount
  }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps())(Cart);
```

Comment: The way this is written is valid, so it could be a problem with how you're exporting `incrementCount`/`decrementCount`, can you update your question with that code? (Side note: defining `mapDispatch` as a function and calling it is unnecessary, you can just define it as an object and pass the object to `connect`. See this article for more info: https://daveceddia.com/redux-mapdispatchtoprops-object-form/)

Answer (score 3):

You are calling the function instead of passing its reference

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps())(Cart);
// ------------------------------------------------------^^--------
```

change to this

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Cart);
```

---

An alternative is to just not use `mapDispatchToProps` at all and use the dispatch your connected component receives

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Cart);
```

and then using dispatch

```
this.props.dispatch(decrementCount())
```

Comment: not working for me , by the way thank for your comment.
this is my app.js

import React,{Component} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import {Cart} from './home';
// import store from './store'

// import {Provider} from 'react-redux';

class App extends React.Component {

  render(){
  return (
   <div>
      <Cart/>
     </div>
  );
}
}

export default App;

Comment: and index.js

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

import store from './store'

import {Provider} from 'react-redux';



ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));

Comment: Instead of saying it's not working, post a codesandbox where you're replicating the issue